# How to query the rows that fall in current timedate with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

How can I query the rows that fall in current timedate?

article table,

```
id   title   date_from                 date_to
1    a       2014-08-11 00:00:00       2014-08-25 00:00:00
2    b       2014-08-01 00:00:00       2014-08-25 00:00:00
3    c       2014-08-09 00:00:00       2014-08-10 00:00:00
```

query (not working obviously),

```
SELECT 
    p.*

FROM article AS p

WHERE p.date_from >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
AND p.date_to <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
AND p.type = 'post'
```

The result I am after,

```
1    a       2014-08-11 00:00:00       2014-08-25 00:00:00
2    b       2014-08-01 00:00:00       2014-08-25 00:00:00
```

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN something AND smething_else ??? - and where does p.type come from?

Comment: Sorry, type should not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so

```
SELECT 
    p.*

FROM t AS p

WHERE NOW() >= p.date_from 
AND  NOW() <= p.date_to
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/278196/3)

Using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
SELECT 
    p.*

FROM t AS p

WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= p.date_from 
AND  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  <= p.date_to
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/278196/4)

Answer (score 1):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the exact time when you execute that query, but you have inside you columns the begining of the day as date.
try with `CURRENT_DATE`